# Classifying the values present in a single column using SQL into their respective datatypes?

Tags: sql, t-sql, types, aster

I have been trying to classify the a set values present in a single column (just like above) into datatypes. The problem being that i am using Aster SQL environment 
(availability of function and the environment as a whole is very limited). Another problem is there are a lot of junk values in the column, a lot of symbols, characters etc. which makes it hard to even hard-code the problem. The structure is something like:

```
FeatureValue
123
24
15.6
17:15
abc
12/18/2014
17/222222           
abc1200                                
001001oo             
positve+              
+1
```

I would like the solution to be a SQL query. The end result should be something like:

```
FeatureValue    Type
123             Numeric
24              Numeric
15.6            Numeric
17:15           String (?time)
abc             String
12/18/2014      Date
17/222222       String
abc1200         String
001001oo        String
positve+        String
+1              String
```

I coded a little, but this solution is not very reliable. What I did was:

```
case 
            when upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%A%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%B%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%C%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%D%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%E%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%F%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%G%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%H%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%I%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%J%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%K%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%L%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%M%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%N%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%O%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%P%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%Q%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%R%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%S%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%T%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%U%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%V%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%W%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%X%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%Y%' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%Z%' and       
            upper(trim(feature_value)) <>'' and
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%+%' and 
            upper(trim(feature_value)) is not null and
            --upper(trim(feature_value))<>'-' and 
            upper(trim(feature_value))<>'NULL' and 
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%/%' and 
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%-%' and 
            upper(trim(feature_value)) not like '%:%' and 
            feature_value is not null 
                then 'NUMERIC'           
            else 'STRING'
        end as value_type
```

Comment: Which SQL engine? can you tag that as well? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes, I tagged Aster engine. I have did some sort of hard coding, added in the question now.

Comment: Why would you consider +1 to be a string and not a number?

Comment: @Sparky because how are you gonna use it in calculations. My understanding tells me that '+1' means more than 1, but it can be 1.2 or 1.5 or 100. Plus, it will be very non-nonsensical and might lead to skewed analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to get the CASE-nightmare a bit more under control with a character range in the LIKE-statement:

```
CASE WHEN upper(trim(feature_value)) NOT LIKE '%[A-Z/-+:]%'
    AND upper(trim(feature_value)) NOT LIKE ''
    AND upper(trim(feature_value)) IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'NUMERIC'
    ELSE 'STRING'
END AS value_type
```

Modify/extend as needed.